# c count lines in a file avoid EOF

Tags: c, eof, wc

On numerous sources, you can find a simple C program to count the number of lines in a file. I'm using one of these.

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {   
    FILE *file;
    long count_lines = 0;
    char chr;
 
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while ((chr = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        count_lines += chr == '\n';
    }
    fclose(file); //close file.
    printf("%ld %s\n", count_lines, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it fails to count the num. of lines in [Top2Billion-probable-v2.txt](https://weakpass.com/wordlist/1858). It stops on the line

```
<F0><EE><E7><E0><EB><E8><FF>
```

and outputs

```
1367044 Top2Billion-probable-v2.txt
```

when it should output `1973218846` lines. `wc -l` somehow avoids the problem (and is amazingly faster).

Should I give up with a correct C implementation of counting the number of lines of a file or how should I space the special characters as `wc` does?

Comment: `chr` needs to be an int, not a char. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: `fgetc` does not return a `char` but an `int`. How would you be able to distinguish a `0xFF` from an `<EOF>` with a `char`?

Comment: Also try opening the file with `"rb"` instead of just `"r"`. `wc` is probably faster because it reads in larger blocks of data instead of individual characters, and searches these using optimized functions such as `strchr`.

Comment: You're right. I should have used `int` that solves the issue.

Comment: reading in `rb` brings no speedup, btw.

Comment: And this is strange that typical internet solutions, at least those that I googled, don't mention the caveat that `chr` should be `int` and not a char.

Comment: Please post the solution so that I mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgetc()` returns the character read as an unsigned char **cast to an int or EOF**. Hence declaring `chr` as `int` instead of `char` should solve the issue.